# How to use (or) in if statement?

Tags: if-statement, lisp, common-lisp, equality

Here is my if-statement

```
(if (equal 1 (or 3 2 1))
    (write "ok")
    (write "wrong"))
```

I trying to execute code below:

```
(equal 1 (or 3 2 1))
```

It returns nil

How cat i use (or) properly in this case?

Comment: OR returns the first true value. Which is 3. 3 is never equal to 1.
You may want to tell us what you want to do. What does 'properly' mean?

Comment: What you're doing now is like `1 == (3 || 2 || 1)` in most other languages. That of course makes no sense. I assume you're looking for `(member 1 '(3 2 1) :test #'=)`.

Comment: It works with integers, but not works with list of strings. ex: `(member "TAG" '("TAA" "TAG"))`

Comment: You have to use the correct comparison operator. `=` is for numeric equality, `STRING=` for case-sensitive strings, `STRING-EQUAL` for case-insensitive strings, and so on.

Comment: Thank you! Where can I read more about `:test #'=` construction?

Comment: You should read the book [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/). [Chapter 11](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/collections.html) explains the `:TEST` keyword argument. You could also read the [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_ba.htm).

Comment: Why not make those comments an answer, @jkiiski?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing now is like `1 == (3 || 2 || 1)` in most other languages. That of course makes no sense. What you're looking for is

```lisp
(member 1 '(3 2 1) :test #'=)
```

By default [`MEMBER`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm) looks for a specific object by using [`EQL`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm). This works for primitives such as integers, but it won't work for strings or mixed integers and floats. You should use the `:TEST`-keyword argument to specify the correct comparison function for whatever type your items are.

```
(member 1.0 '(3 2.0 1) :test #'=) ; numeric
(member "fOo" '("foo" "FOO" "fOo") :test #'string=) ; case-sensitive
(member "foo" '("FOO" "BAR" "QUUX") :test #'string-equal) ; case-insensitive
```

Comment: It actually makes sense. It just requires John McCarthy's `amb` operator, or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` instead of the `or` if you are willing to convert your expression to a list.

```
(defun test (x)
  (if (find x '(1 2 3))
      (format t "equal")
      (format t "not equal")))
```

Comment: You could use find, but member would probably be much more idiomatic here.  Especially if you ever need to check whether NIL in a list (since find would return NIL, which is false).

Comment: Your are correct. I forgot about the NIL case :/
The member is much better suited.

Answer (score 0):

First of that. How really works OR operation on lisp? Let's begin with a few examples.

- (OR 5 4 3) -> 5
- (OR 1 2 3) -> 1
- (OR nil 7 8) -> 7

The output of OR function is just the 1st element not equal to NIL.

So in your code:
(equal 1 3) -> NIL

This function checks if an element n exist in a list l

for example

- (findout 1 '(3 2 1)) -> T
- (findout 4 '(3 2 1)) -> NIL

`(defun findout (n l)
    (if (null l)
        nil
        (if (equal (car l) n)
            t
            (findout n (cdr l))
        )
    )
)`

And then you can change your code like this:

```
(if (findout 1 '(3 2 1))
(write "yes")
(write "no")
```

)